# Trying to Display Number of Posts in Term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, count

I am trying to display the number of posts within each of my custom taxonomy terms. I just need to show if there's  2, 3 10, etc # of posts within my terms.  This is my code. Looking for a way to include it in this and still be able to style it individually.

```
<?php

        $libargs=array(  
            'hide_empty'        => 0,  
            'parent'        => 0,  
            'taxonomy'      => 'industrygroups');  


            $libcats=get_categories($libargs);  

            foreach($libcats as $lc){ 
            echo '<div class="col-lg-3">';
                $termlink = get_term_link( $lc->slug, 'industrygroups' ); 

        ?>
           <p class="text-center"> <a href="<?php echo $termlink; ?>">
 <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="<?php the_field('taximage', 'industrygroups_'.$lc->term_id); ?>" />
   <br />
            <?php echo $lc->name; ?></a></p>
                     <?php the_field('basictext', 'industrygroups_'.$lc->term_id); ?>


        <?php   echo '</div>'; }?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The category objects returned by `get_categories()` include a property of `count`:

```
$lc->count
```